# Bootstrap 3 to 4 Migration in File Upload button and Input size issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, migration, bootstrap-4

I have been using the below Snippet for a while now. But when I try to move the same code to Bootstrap 4, The Button size and Input Box size are not aligning.

#### Bootstrap 3 File Upload Snippet

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                Choose File <input type="file" id="pdf-file" name="pdf_file" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pdf-name" placeholder="Select the PDF File" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Bootstrap 4 File Upload Snippet

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-10">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                Choose File <input type="file" id="pdf-file" name="pdf_file" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pdf-name" placeholder="Select the PDF File" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Please help me migrate the above code to Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons)
On another note, Bootstrap 4 has some new great features when it comes to file inputs. You can learn more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-file-input)

Answer (score 1):

you try this way

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
   label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
  });

  $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {
      
      var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
          log = label;
      
      if( input.length ) {
          input.val(log);
      } else {
          if( log ) alert(log);
      }
     
  });
  function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }
          
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
  }

  $("#imgInp").change(function(){
      readURL(this);
  });  
 });
```

```css
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}

#img-upload{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload Image</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    Browse… <input type="file" id="imgInp">
                </span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
        </div>
        <img id='img-upload'/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. It is working fine in Bootstrap 3 in code. The Problem I have is that it's not working in Bootstrap 4.